# Is graph Isomorphism distributive on Cartesian Product of graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

We know that $G \mathbin\square H$ = $H \mathbin\square G.$ My question is that if $\mathbin\pi(G) \mathbin \square \mathbin\pi(H)$ same  as $G \mathbin\square H$? How do I approach this problem. I haven't got a clue.

Comment: What do you mean by $\operatorname{Isomorph}(G)$? this isn't standard notation. (Also, "we know that $G \mathbin\square H$" makes about as much sense to me as "we know that $17$".)

Comment: Normally graph isomorphism indicates something a graph is isomorphic to.

Comment: Are you asking $G \simeq J \wedge H \simeq K \implies G \square H \simeq J \square K$?

Comment: Well, I consulted with my professor and notation is pi where pi is a permutation of vertices applied (which yield a bijection implying an isomorph). @Misha Lavrov

Comment: It took a while to understand your notation and yes, that's exactly what I am after @Q the platypus. Props for the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below $\pi$ and $\kappa$ are bijective maps with domains $V(G)$ and $V(H)$, respectively.

---

By definition of a Cartesian product graph, $\pi(G) \Box \kappa(H)$ is the graph with:

- vertex set $V(\pi(G)) \times V(\kappa(H))$, and
- edges between distinct $(\pi(g),\kappa(h))$ and $(\pi(g'),\kappa(h'))$ if and only if $\pi(g)=\pi(g')$ or $\kappa(h)=\kappa(h')$.

To see this is isomorphic to $G \Box H$, we apply an isomorphism to $G \Box H$: $$(g,h) \mapsto (\pi(g),\kappa(h)) \tag{*}.$$ After this transformation, the graph has the vertex set $V(\pi(G)) \times V(\kappa(H))$, and adjacency is defined between distinct vertices $(\pi(g),\kappa(h))$ and $(\pi(g'),\kappa(h'))$ if and only if $\pi(g)=\pi(g')$ or $\kappa(h)=\kappa(h')$.

Thus $(^*)$ is an isomorphism from $G \Box H$ to $\pi(G) \Box \kappa(H)$.

Comment: Is it possible to get pi or kappa given I know G, H pi(G), and kappa(H)? Or is it like integer factorization?

Comment: It depends on what "know G" and "know pi(G)" means.  If you just have two isomorphic graphs, there may be distinct isomorphisms between them.  (But if you have, say, G and pi(G) drawn identically with vertices relabelled, then you can easily deduce pi.)

Comment: I am considering an adjacency matrix representation of the graphs, unlabelled of course. Now, I have adj. matrix forms of G,H, pi(G) \mathbin\square kappa(H). Is it now possible to get unique pi and kappa? Is it possible to get pi(G) and kappa(H) from G,H,  pi(G) \mathbin\square kappa(H)

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, how do I generate a graph with no automorphs at all and I am writing a paper and can I cite you as a reference? If so, how?

Comment: If $G \Box H$ has a unique isomorphism with $\pi(G) \Box \kappa(H)$, when we can compute it and deduce $\pi$ and $\kappa$.  Otherwise, it might not be possible to deduce $\pi$ and $\kappa$; they might not even be unique (which would happen if $G$ or $H$ has an automorphism).

Comment: The Frucht graph has no automorphisms; most Latin square graphs have no automorphisms.  I don't know off the top of my head how to efficiently generate random automorphism-free graphs.

Comment: I'd like to get some ideas from you regarding my paper I mentioned, would you be free to join me in a personal chat?

Comment: You oversimplified the definition of $\square$ in your proof, but the general idea of the actual proof is the same.

Comment: @Taneli Huuskonen, please explain at which part I oversimplified.

Comment: I was commenting on the answer by @RebeccaJ.Stones . Anyway, the oversimplified part is the condition for adjacency. In the current (faulty) version of the proof, adjacency in the product $G\mathbin{\square}H$ doesn't depend on adjacency in $G$ or $H$. In my opinion, correcting the proof would be an excellent exercise for you.